# Dynamically data type discovery while creating documents elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is below requirement possible in Elasticsearch?

1. I create one document in ES with type user:

```
{
  "name": "Michael",
  "confirmed": false,
  "rating": 19
}
```

2. When I get the mapping for user type, It gives the following:

```
{
  "indextest": {
    "mappings": {
      "user": {
        "properties": {
          "confirmed": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "rating": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

3. Now I created new document in user type again with following json:

```
{
  "name": "Michael",
  "confirmed": false,
  "rating": "asddf"
}
```

It gives a bad request because of data type conflict for rating field.

Is that possible, ES automatically detect the data type and update the mapping

Comment: The mapping of a field cannot be updated once it's been created. You can change very few things and it is definitely not allowed to change the type of a field.